# How to check the email addres is belong to which group by EWS?

Tags: exchangewebservices

I know that how to expend detail from an email group, but may I know any method to revert to check the email is belong to which group?  I see that Outlook 2010 can show "Member Of" tab when highlighted a contact, but how I can do similar thing by API?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was posted on the [MSDN Exchange Server Development forum](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/6ac0cbbf-c886-4159-a73d-44105a77c166/how-to-get-all-the-distribution-lists-a-user-is-member-of-using-ews-managed-api?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment) and here's what Glen Scales said:

"EWS wont give you details about group membership of a users (it also wont return extra properties from Active Directory like you could in Mapi). A few things that you can do in EWS is expand a group using the expandGroup operation  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.expandgroup%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx.

The other thing you can do with Groups if you have Exchange 2010 is take advantage of any of the MailTip operations.

For what you want to do you would be better to use LDAP directory to lookup Active directory and get the group membership or if you really wanted to use an Exchange API look at using the Exchange Management Shell cmdlets."

The link he provided doesn't work - I assume he was pointing here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.expandgroup(v=exchg.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.expandgroup%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx).